# Repair Windows 7 without the disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, file-corruption, system-repair-disc

Is it possible to repair Windows 7 without the disk?

This PC hasn't been scanned for a while. Last time the PC was on, it was scanned using Avast Free Antivirus. It detected some corrupt zip files, worms, etc in the Windows folder. I chose to delete them all.  At 50% through the process, I decided to manually restart it by pressing the power button. As it came back on, Windows Repair ran.

Is the repair provided different from the repair the CD provides?

Comment: I don't understand "repair windows disabling the windows to start". Is there maybe some text on the screen you could share?

Comment: When you start the PC try to hit F8 key continue and you will get the option of `Last known good config` and try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to repair issue without the disk via [Last Known Working Configuration](http://bit.ly/nhSnTj). It also possible via System Restore in Safe Mode. See steps below.

#### Using Windows 7 System Restore via Safe Mde

1. Boot up the system
2. Push and Hold <kbd>F8</kbd>
3. Select **Safe Mode** under *Advanced Boot Options*
4. Log into an account
5. Click the **Start** icon
6. Type: `System Restore`
7. Follow the *System Restore* wizard

   - Use Recommended options
   - If Recommended options doesn't work: try using an older restore point.

---

If you are missing your Windows Vista/7 installation DVD, create one using these [instructions](http://bit.ly/qFbKS7). Follow the steps below once you created the disk.

#### Using Windows 7 System Restore via Installation or Restore Disk

1. Boot with *Installation DVD* in your computer
2. Select boot from disk
3. Select the **Repair your computer**
4. Click **Next**
5. Choose **System Restore**
6. Click **Next**
7. Select the Windows/Vista drive
8. Click **Finish**

Comment: but i dont have a disk

Comment: Have you tried Last Known Working Configuration? If you can't get to that screen, then you will need to get a blank DVD and create a Recovery or Installation Disk.

Comment: You can borrow Windows DVD from any friend of yours it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SgtOJ how to create a recovery or installation Disk?

Comment: Ideally you create one before Windows is corrupt. However, there is a an alternative. You can find the instructions and ISO download at this link: http://bit.ly/qFbKS7 ... Good luck @user913233